# Are CASE statements or OR statements faster in a WHERE clause? (SQL/BigQuery)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to get some insight in this room for optimization for a SQL query (BigQuery). I have this segment of a WHERE clause that needs to include all instances where h.isEntrance is TRUE or where h.hitNumber = 1. I've tested it back and forth with CASE statements, and with OR statements for them, and the results aren't wholly conclusive.

It seems like the CASE is faster for shorter data pulls, and the OR is faster for longer data pulls, but that doesn't make sense to me. Is there a difference between these or is it likely something else driving this difference? Is one faster/is there another better option for incorporating this logical requirement into my query? Below the statement is my full query for context in case that's helpful.

Also open to any other optimizations I may have overlooked within this query as lowering the runtime for this query is paramount to its usefulness.

Thanks!

```
            (CASE 
                WHEN h.isEntrance = TRUE THEN 'True'
                WHEN h.hitNumber = 1 THEN 'True'
                ELSE 'False'
            END) = 'True'
```

```
    date,
    Medium,
    (CASE
        WHEN REGEXP_Contains(landingpage,r'(?i)sweater|(?i)hoodie') THEN "Apparel | Sweaters"
        WHEN REGEXP_Contains(landingpage,r'(?i)sneaker') AND NOT REGEXP_CONTAINS(landingpage,r'(?i)active') THEN "Footwear | Sneakers"     
        WHEN REGEXP_Contains(landingpage,r'(?i)coats|(?i)jackets') THEN "Apparel | Outerwear"
        WHEN REGEXP_Contains(landingpage,r'(?i)sandal') THEN "Footwear | Sandals"
        WHEN REGEXP_Contains(landingpage,r'(?i)handbags|(?i)bag|(?i)tote') THEN "Handbags"
        WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(landingpage,r'(?i)boots') THEN "Footwear | Boots"
        WHEN REGEXP_Contains(landingpage,r'(?i)beauty|(?i)lipstick|(?i)makeup|(?i)powder|(?i)foundation|(?i)cologne|(?i)dyson-airwrap') THEN "Beauty"
        WHEN REGEXP_Contains(landingpage,r'(?i)dresses|(?i)dress|(?i)cocktail') AND NOT REGEXP_CONTAINS(landingpage,r'(?i)shoe|(?i)shaker|(?i)glasses|(?i)coaster') THEN "Apparel | Dresses"
        WHEN REGEXP_Contains(landingpage,r'(?i)/home|(?i)home decor|(?i)bath|(?i)bedding|(?i)kitchen|(?i)table|(?i)pantry|(?i)electronics|(?i)asweet|(?i)vacuum') THEN "Home"
        WHEN REGEXP_Contains(landingpage,r'(?i)sandal') THEN "Footwear | Sandals"
        WHEN REGEXP_Contains(landingpage,r'(?i)handbags|(?i)bag|(?i)tote') THEN "Handbags"
        WHEN REGEXP_Contains(landingpage,r'(?i)denim|(?i)jeans') THEN "Apparel | Denim"
        WHEN REGEXP_Contains(landingpage,r'(?i)activewear|(?i)active|(?i)legging|(?i)sports-bra|(?i)tennis-skirt|(?i)skort') THEN "Apparel | Activewear"
        WHEN REGEXP_Contains(landingpage,r'(?i)swim') THEN "Apparel | Swimwear"
        WHEN REGEXP_Contains(landingpage,r'(?i)accessories') AND NOT REGEXP_Contains(landingpage,r'(?i)jewelry') THEN "Accessories"
        WHEN REGEXP_Contains(landingpage,r'(?i)jewelry|(?i)watch') THEN "Jewelry"
        WHEN REGEXP_Contains(landingpage,r'(?i)shoe|(?i)boot|(?i)flat|(?i)heels|(?i)slie|(?i)slide|(?i)oxford|(?i)loafer|(?i)slipper|(?i)sneaker') THEN "Footwear"
        WHEN REGEXP_Contains(landingpage,r'(?i)clothing|(?i)lingerie|(?i)t-shirt|(?i)blouse|(?i)top|(?i)bra') AND NOT REGEXP_CONTAINS(landingpage,r'(?i)active') THEN "Apparel"
        ELSE "Other"
    END) as Segment,
    (CASE
        WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(Campaign,r'(?i)_display_|(?i)retention|(?i)acquisition') THEN 'Display'  
        WHEN REGEXP_Contains(Campaign,r'(?i)_m_') AND REGEXP_Contains(Campaign,r'(?i)low_nd|(?i)mid_nd|(?i)_mid_ex_') AND Medium != "organic" THEN 'N'
        WHEN REGEXP_Contains(Campaign,r'(?i)low_nd|(?i)pla_shopping|(?i)mid_nd|(?i)_mid_ex_') AND NOT REGEXP_CONTAINS(Campaign,r'(?i)_n_') AND Medium !="organic" THEN ''
        WHEN REGEXP_Contains(Campaign,r'(?i)nr_|(?i)pla_shopping|(?i)hl_|(?i) nr ') AND NOT REGEXP_CONTAINS(Campaign,r'(?i)_n_') AND Medium !="organic" THEN ''
        WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(Campaign,r'(?i)_terms') AND Medium !="organic" THEN ''
        WHEN Medium = "organic" THEN ""
        ELSE ""
    END) as Site,
    SUM(newUsers) as newUsers,
    SUM(Sessions) as Sessions,
    TRUNC(SUM(Revenue)/1000000,2) as Revenue
    
FROM(    
        SELECT
            date,
            trafficSource.campaign Campaign,
            trafficSource.medium as Medium, 
            SUM(totals.transactionRevenue) as Revenue,
            SUM(totals.newVisits) as newUsers,
            SUM(totals.visits) as Sessions,
            h.page.pagePath as landingPage
        FROM
            `database.ga_sessions_20*`, UNNEST(hits) as h
            WHERE h.type = 'PAGE'AND
            (CASE 
                WHEN h.isEntrance = TRUE THEN 'True'
                WHEN h.hitNumber = 1 THEN 'True'
                ELSE 'False'
            END) = 'True'
            /*(h.isEntrance = TRUE OR h.hitNumber = 1)*/
            AND REGEXP_CONTAINS(trafficSource.medium, r'cpc|organic')
            AND PARSE_DATE('%y%m%d', _TABLE_SUFFIX) between
            DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(current_date(), interval 2 MONTH),MONTH), interval 1 DAY) and
            LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(current_date(), interval 1 MONTH),MONTH)
            Group by date, Medium, landingpage,  Campaign
)
Group by date,Segment, Medium, Site
ORDER BY Segment
```

Comment: It honestly is probably out of your control unless you are evaluating a clustered column.  Both a case statement and a chain of ORs will "short-circuit" when the first TRUE is evaluated. So if you know the distribution of your data, it would probably be somewhat faster if you put your most likely conditions first.

Comment: The problem with BOTH is they tend to break the ability to use an index for optimization, which cuts to the core of database performance.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Is there an alternative to using either that can achieve the same sort of result?

Comment: @rtenha, that was a great point.. I tried flipping them around, and it took almost a whole second longer (on my shorter timeframe, so probably saved 5 sec on the full timeframe), so I guess I lucked into the better option, but I really hadn't considered the fact that the order mattered

Comment: @Charlie Sometimes `coalesce()`, but often it means re-thinking table structure to, for example, add a computed column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find out which version consumes less resources and is faster - execute them, then head over to the [Execution details](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-plan-explanation) and [compare numbers](https://medium.com/slalom-build/using-bigquery-execution-plans-to-improve-query-performance-af141b0cc33d).
[image]

Answer (score 0):

From a code craft viewpoint alone, I would probably always write your `CASE` expression as this:

```sql
WHERE h.isEntrance = TRUE OR h.hitNumber = 1
```

As to whether which version would be more optimal, I might expect the above, as the `CASE` expression might force BigQuery to materialize an intermediate value, and then do a comparison on it.

In any case (no pun intended), this point is most likely not the biggest performance bottleneck in your query.

Answer (score 0):

I ran a `case when` vs `where` clause against a 4 billion row table.
It made no real difference timewise.
Slot time consumed is also similar.